# How to force tests to stop running a test suite after a specified test failed?

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-unittest

I have a test suite written in Selenium Webdriver/Python 2.7 consisting of several test cases. Some of test cases are so critical that if they fail the whole test is failed and there is no need to run test cases after that.

```
class TestSuite1(unittest.TestCase)
     def setUp(self):
         pass

     def test1(self):
         return True

     def test2(self):
         return false

     def test3(self):
         return True

     # This is a critical test
     def test4(self):
         return false

     def test5(self):
         return True

     def tearDown(self):
         pass
```

So, I want to stop the whole test run when test4 fails (test run should continue when test2 fails) because it is critical. I know we can use decorators but I am looking for a more efficient way since I have about 20 critical tests in my test run and it does not seem efficient to use 20 flag for all test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like:

```
import unittest

class CustomResult(unittest.TestResult):
    def addFailure(self, test, err):
        critical = ['test4', 'test7']
        if test._testMethodName in critical:
            print("Critical Failure!")
            self.stop()
        unittest.TestResult.addFailure(self, test, err)


class TestSuite1(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test1(self):
        return True

    def test2(self):
        return False

    def test3(self):
        return True

    # This is a critical test
    def test4(self):
        self.fail()
        pass

    def test5(self):
        print("test5")
        return True

    def tearDown(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    runner = unittest.runner.TextTestRunner(resultclass=CustomResult)
    unittest.main(testRunner=runner)
```

You may have to adjust this depending on how you invoke your testing.

If `self.fail()` (in `test4`) is commented out, 5 methods are tested.  But if it is not commented out, the test prints "Critical Failure!" and stops.  In my case, only 4 tests ran.

It might also be smart to name those methods so that when sorted lexicographically, they come first, that way if a critical failure will happen, there is no time wasted testing the other methods.

Output (with `self.fail()`):

```
Critical Failure!
Ran 4 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Output (without `self.fail()`):

```
test5
Ran 5 tests in 0.001s

OK
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it seems that it should work fine but it is not working for me. With or without self.fail(), all tests are being run.

Comment: @Mahmor, how are you running your tests?  If the code inside `if __name__ == '__main__':` isn't what starts your tests, then all tests will run.

Comment: I am running them through CLI using python -m unittest a.py. I have copied the exact code you have posted in a.py. Is that right?

Comment: @Mahmor That code will work if you run it as a script (e.g. `python a.py`) -- I'll look into hooking the default unittest runner, but I'm not sure that's possible.