# Stop Test suite Execution python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, unit-testing

Given this test suite :

```
import unittest

class unittestDex(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_page1(self):
       pass

    def test_page2(self):
       pass

    def test_page3_isCritical(self):
       #I am passing isCritical variable as boolean, this will be received after the test is executed, true/false
       if isCritical == True:
          #stop the whole execution, test_page4 shoudn't run anymore

    def test_page4(self):
       pass

    @staticmethod
    def main():
        suite = unittest.TestSuite()
        suite.addTest(unittestDex(metname='test_page1')
        suite.addTest(unittestDex(metname='test_page2')
        suite.addTest(unittestDex(metname='test_page3')
        suite.addTest(unittestDex(metname='test_page4')
        unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

Is there a way to stop the suite run somehow if  the isCritical condition is met?
Basically i'm asking if anybody found a way to stop a test suite run.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29463896/how-to-force-tests-to-stop-running-a-test-suite-after-a-specified-test-failed) solution dosen't really work for me because it somehow merges all tests together and runs as a unit and i dont want that :

Tried `pytest.exit('Test suit exited manually') and raise Exception`  but the tests dosen't stop from executing, the next test method starts immediately after

Answer (score 0):

You can use pytest -x to stop test suite after first  failure.
value can be configured using --maxfail=num where num is the number of failure

Comment: So I assume this is for linux, like an external command or something ? How do I Integrate it in `if isCritical == True: pytest -x` considering the run is done from pycharm